# php apc.php - password protect

Tags: php, apache, apc

I've installed APC onto apache and have moved the apc.php file into the document root so I can see it.

I was reading about setting a user/password on the file

```
defaults('ADMIN_USERNAME','apc'); // Admin Username
defaults('ADMIN_PASSWORD','password'); // Admin Password - CHANGE THIS TO ENABLE!!!
```

What does this user/pass actually do?

I can still view the page as before - just interested in its purpose.

Also is it important to start outsiders view this file (I assume so) and how would this best be done?

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in to the APC page allows you to clear the cache.  Other than that and viewing the statistics of the cache, there's not much to apc.php.  The best way to restrict access to it would be an .htaccess rule to either only allow your IP address to access it or a password protect it with the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

To password protect a file check out http://webdesign.about.com/od/htaccess/ht/password_1_file.htm